# Bidirectional menu items in Toolbar not mirrored properly

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-optionsmenu

After adding some menu items to a `Toolbar` they are not behaving as expected. The direction of the arrows is correct in LTR (left-to-right) layout. However, when RTL (right-to-left) layout is used the posiiton of the icons changes as expected but not the direction of them. Why do these icons refuse to mirror themselves when `android:autoMirrored="true"` has been declared with the drawable XMLs? My manifest already contains `android:supportsRtl="true"`.

**Guides consulted**

- [Android Developers > Support layout mirroring](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages#SupportLayoutMirroring)
- [Material.io > Bidirectionality](https://material.io/design/usability/bidirectionality.html)

**According to Material.io**

[image]

[image]

**LTR direction**

[image]

**RTL direction**

[image]

**Back arrow**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:width="24dp" android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M20,11H7.83l5.59,-5.59L12,4l-8,8 8,8 1.41,-1.41L7.83,13H20v-2z"/>
</vector>
```

**Forward arrow**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:width="24dp" android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M12,4l-1.41,1.41L16.17,11H4v2h12.17l-5.58,5.59L12,20l8,-8z"/>
</vector>
```

**Menu items XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".WebviewActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_webbrowser_back"
        android:title="@string/back"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_webbrowser_forward"
        android:title="@string/forward"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_webbrowser_reload"
        android:title="@string/reload"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: same problem here

Comment: @Swarthy46 - Have you got any solution?

Comment: @MohammadMisbah Still no solution as of 10/1/2021.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me, and the only way I found to fix it is to create mirrored icons and put them in the `drawable-ldrtl` folder.